# Angular: How to $broadcast from Factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items and I need to get a message (saying Item added!) in the navbar whenever a new item is added.

The function addItem() (ng-click on the Add Item button) is in the ItemFactory and from there I seem to not be able to broadcast it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>{{ text }}

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">List of items | {{ alertItemAdded }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newItem" placeholder="Add an item">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addItem(newItem)">Add Item</button>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container" ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newItem" placeholder="Add an item">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addItem(newItem)">Add Item</button>
                        </form>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in items">

                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div>{{ item }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-s" ng-click="removeItem($index)">Remove Item</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


angular.module('MyApp',[]);

angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ItemFactory){

    $scope.text = "Text from the Main Controller";

    $scope.addItem = function(newItem){
        ItemFactory.addItem(newItem);
    }

});

angular.module('MyApp').controller('NavCtrl', function($scope){

    // $on
    $scope.$on('itemAdded', function(event, data){
        $scope.alertItemAdded = data;
    });

});

angular.module('MyApp').controller('ContentCtrl', function($scope, ItemFactory){

    $scope.items = ItemFactory.getItem();

    $scope.removeItem = function($index){
        ItemFactory.removeItem($index);
    }

});

angular.module('MyApp').factory('ItemFactory', function(){

    var items = [
        'Item 1', 
        'Item 2', 
        'Item 3'
    ];

    return {
        getItem : function() {
            return items;
        },
        addItem : function(item){
            items.push(item);
            // $broadcast
            $scope.$broadcast('itemAdded', 'Item added!');
        },
        removeItem : function($index){
            items.splice($index, 1);
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: import $rootScope in factory and broadcast from here ?

Comment: This is a very bad use case for broadcast. Why do people love broadcast so much....

Comment: I actually don't recommend using $rootScope in a factory. There's some cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @Okazari, totally agree. Need to make code maintainable, not just runnable

Comment: I'm working on a plunker to provide you a clean solution

Comment: @ABOS Added a clean solution, working as i like with services references. Tell me if you have anything to say about this

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but the overal looks nice and clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject $rootScope into your factory and use $broadcast from there.

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('ItemFactory', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope){

    var items = [
        'Item 1', 
        'Item 2', 
        'Item 3'
    ];

    return {
        getItem : function() {
            return items;
        },
        addItem : function(item){
            items.push(item);
            // $broadcast
            $rootScope.$broadcast('itemAdded', 'Item added!');
        },
        removeItem : function($index){
            items.splice($index, 1);
        }
    };
```

}]);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution for you.

See it working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pILrvnSxJjCm12WsHU7L?p=preview)

Let me explain how all of this works.

Your message looks like this :

```
<span ng-if="alertItemAdded.recentAdd">Item added !</span>
```

It will show only when "alterITemAdded.recenAdd" is true. You'll use this to make the message disapear if you need.

You factory look like this now :

```
angular.module('MyApp').service('ItemService', function(){

    var service = {};

    //I'll always wrap my data in a sub object.
    service.notification = {};

    service.notification.recentAdd=false;

    service.items = {};

    service.items.list = [
        'Item 1', 
        'Item 2', 
        'Item 3'
    ];

    service.items.addItem = function(item){
          service.items.list.push(item);
          service.notification.recentAdd=true;
          console.log(service);
    }

    service.items.removeItem = function($index){
          service.items.list.splice($index, 1);
    }

    return service;

});
```

I'm using service instead of factory. But there is almost no difference, it's just a matter of taste.

Here is your controllers

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ItemService){

    $scope.text = "Text from the Main Controller";

});

angular.module('MyApp').controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, ItemService){

    //IMPORTANT POINT : I bind it the sub object. Not to the value. To access the value i'll use $scope.alterItemAdded.recentAdd
    $scope.alertItemAdded = ItemService.notification;
    //I don't have to redeclare the function. I just bind it to the service function.
    $scope.addItem = ItemService.items.addItem;
});

angular.module('MyApp').controller('ContentCtrl', function($scope, ItemService){

    $scope.items = ItemService.items.list;

    $scope.addItem = ItemService.items.addItem;

    $scope.removeItem = function($index){
        ItemService.items.removeItem($index);
    }

});
```

Important point :

I always bind my vars to a sub object. Why ? In fact if i did 
     $scope.alertItemAdded = ItemService.notifications.recentAdd

When i do something like this in my service

```
 service.notifications.recentAdd = true;
```

It will create a new variable and put the reference into service.notifications.recentAdd. The $scope.alertItemAdded was bind to the previous reference and wont see the update.

Doing this :

```
$scope.alterItemAdded = ItemService.notification
```

And using the value in the ng-if clause or anything else. I prevent the reference link to break. If i do in the service

```
service.notification.recentAdd = true
```

I'll create a new var with a new reference for "recentAdd" but i keep the same reference for "notification". The binding in the controller will be keep and the value recentAdd will be updated in the view.

If you have more question feel free to ask.

Comment: I appreciate and understand your clean solution. Nevertheless, I've given best answer to Tom because I'm a beginner in AngularJS and Tom's answer is more straightforward (easy to use for me right now on my existing code). But I understand that your answer is more advanced and I'll try to start using your approach in the future.

Comment: @M4i4 No problems, feel free to choose the one who answered the best your needs. Anyway using $rootScope is not recommended at all. Just care to not use it too often and it should be ok for you ;) My answer isn't specially advanced. It's basic angular service/factory use cases, learning this will save you in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You not injected $scope to factory, and you cant actually, use $rootScope instead

Answer (score -2):

`$broadcast` goes from top to bottom so you should use `$rootScope` to perform a `$broadcast` to all `$scope` elements below it.

- Inject `$rootScope` in your factory
- $rootScope.$broadcast('itemAdded, 'Item added!')