# accessing multiple parent hierarchy in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a line of code where I am accessing some value from current scope's parent .This current scope has multiple parent ,code is given below -

```
var hash = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.outline_field_usage;
```

Is there any way to void this kind of code where I can avoid accessing `outline_field_usage` element without using . operator . This code is written in side a directive like given below:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'column.html',
    link: linker,
    replace: true,
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        console.log("remove Item --------");
        console.log($scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.outline_field_usage);
        var hash = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.outline_field_usage;
        for (var k in hash) {
            // use hasOwnProperty to filter out keys from the Object.prototype
            if (hash.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                console.log('key is: ' + k + ', value is: ' + hash[k].is_entry_dragged);
            }
        }
    }]
};
```

Comment: You should use a service or a factory to share the property - Some information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352627/angular-how-to-broadcast-from-factory/30353826#30353826

Answer (score 0):

well Not sure how did it works , but instead of using

```
var hash = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.outline_field_usage;
```

i just tried like ---

```
var hash = $scope.outline_field_usage;
```

and it worked.

Comment: Child scopes inherit parent properties