# Pass object to a controller using state.go() in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

So I want to pass an object(json)(ex: person entity) as parameter for state.go() without send it by url.
I tried using params like this

```
     .state('send-to',{
        url:'/:id/options',
        views:{
            'content@':{
                   templateUrl:'page.jsp',
                   params:      ['ref'],
                   controller:'optionCtrl'
                  }
            }       
        })
```

and in my controller1 i use this:

```
 $state.go('home.referentiel.option',{id:$scope.selected,ref:p});
```

and in my controller 'optionCtrl' i use this:

```
 $scope.selectedReferentiel = $stateParams.ref;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a shared service to store the entity?

Comment: @ tymeJV i don't know why, but the probleme is i will do it for multiple objects.

Comment: @tymeJV is right, if you want an exemple you can check my answer on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30353826/2516560